# Emit event with parameters from store

Tags: reactjs, flux

We are building a React application using Flux. For our first Flux project we wanted to use the plain vanilla implementation proposed by Facebook.

For most actions we emit a change from one or more stores and the registered component functions run and call a store method to get the updated data. This work very well. Now we have a scenario where I would rather send out the bit of data "inside" the emit event and not store it in the store for retrieval by the component, i.e. I would like the registered function to receive a parameter. I Googled around but could not find such an example. Is there any established pattern or method of doing this?

Comment: You can do that with Reflux.

Comment: @JanakaStevens - Thanks for the tip. Since we decided to go with plain vanilla Flux in this project, I would rather not bring in a Flux library, especially not one that omits large parts of the architecture.

Comment: With vanilla Flux I haven't come across this either, but I suspect it is by design: keep the emit events simple ("store XYZ changed"), and have all listening components (or other stores) look for themselves if the change is relevant. 

Not passing parameters inside change emit events makes debugging also easier: if communication between store and component breaks down, you do only need to dive into store and component. No need to debug the message itself.

Comment: @wintvelt - I agree. We ended up storing the data from the action and doing a regular emit and the component queries the store for the data. Thank you.